# xsl Create on xml document from Multiple with style sheet

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm sure this is simple but I can't getting to do what I need to. Will appreciate some help. What it is supposed to happen is in the comments and below is what I have done. Below the stye sheet, I copied 3 of xml files as examples for debugging. Appreciate it as I can't figure it out.

I have MULTIPLE xml documents. Each file name is formatted with the word *dept* plus the department number and .xml (i.e., depta00.xml). I need to create a **horizons.xml** file with the data from ALL of the xml files that lists all the employees from each deaprtment. Each document is formatted the same way. Specifically, I need to do the following within the style sheet:

1. Create a template named *getEmployees*
2. Within *getPeople* template, create a variable named depts containing a sequence of the following text strings representing the deaprtment codes: 'a00','c01','d11','d21','e11', and 'e21'
3. After the line to create the *depts* variable, create the *departments* element.
4. Within the *departments* element, insert a `for-each` loop that loops through each entry in the *depts* sequence.
5. For each entry in the *depts* sequence do the following:

   a. Create a variable name *currentDept* equal to the current item in the depts sequence.

   b. Create an element department with an attribute named *deptID* whose value is equal to the value of the *currentDept* variable.

   c. Use the `doc()` function to reference the *deptcurrent.xml* file, where current is the value of the *currentDept* variable. Use `concat()` function to combine the text strings for *dept*, the *currentDept* variable, and teh text string ".xml".

   d. Use the `copy-of` element to copy the contents of the employees element and its descendants to the department element.
6. Save all changes and use XSLT 2.0 processor to generate the result document horizons.xml by applying the *getEmployees* template within the alldepartments.xsl style sheet.

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

   <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template name ="getEmployees">
        <xsl:variable name="depts" select="('a00','c01','d11','d21','e11', 'e21')" as="xs:string*" />
       <xsl:element name="departments">
            <xsl:for-each select="$depts"> <xsl:value-of select="." />
                <xsl:variable name="currentDept"> <xsl:value-of select="$depts" /> </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="department">
                   <xsl:attribute name="deptID"> <xsl:value-of select="$currentDept" /> </xsl:attribute>

                   <xsl:value-of select="doc(concat('dept',$currentDept, '.xml'))" />

                   <xsl:copy-of select="employees" />

              </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML** files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!--
   Employee Information from Department A00
   Filename:         depta00.xml
-->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="alldepartments.xsl"?>
<employees>
   <employee empID="10">
       <firstName>Marylin</firstName>
       <middleInt>A</middleInt>
       <lastName>Johnson</lastName>
       <department>A00</department>
       <phone>3978</phone>
       <email>Johnson.60@example.com/horizons</email>
       <dateHired>2000-01-01</dateHired>
       <title>President</title>
       <edLevel>18</edLevel>
       <gender>F</gender>
       <birthDate>1968-08-24</birthDate>
       <salary>121300</salary>
       <bonus>2300</bonus>
       <commission>9700</commission>
   </employee>
   <employee empID="40">
       <firstName>Heather</firstName>
       <middleInt>D</middleInt>
       <lastName>Gordon</lastName>
       <department>A00</department>
       <phone>3915</phone>
       <email>Gordon.59@example.com/horizons</email>
       <dateHired>2009-03-01</dateHired>
       <title>Manager</title>
       <edLevel>18</edLevel>
       <gender>F</gender>
       <birthDate>1986-06-03</birthDate>
       <salary>85400</salary>
       <bonus>1700</bonus>
       <commission>6500</commission>
   </employee>
</employees>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!--
   Employee Information from Department E11
   Filename:         depte11.xml
-->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="alldepartments.xsl"?>
<employees>
   <employee empID="50">
       <firstName>Alicia</firstName>
       <middleInt>J</middleInt>
       <lastName>Silva</lastName>
       <department>E11</department>
       <phone>6789</phone>
       <email>Silva.50@example.com/horizons</email>
       <dateHired>2013-08-17</dateHired>
       <title>Manager</title>
       <edLevel>16</edLevel>
       <gender>M</gender>
       <birthDate>1960-09-15</birthDate>
       <salary>92400</salary>
       <bonus>1800</bonus>
       <commission>7400</commission>
   </employee>
   <employee empID="90">
       <firstName>Ila</firstName>
       <middleInt>R</middleInt>
       <lastName>Leclerc</lastName>
       <department>E11</department>
       <phone>5498</phone>
       <email>Leclerc.51@example.com/horizons</email>
       <dateHired>2005-08-15</dateHired>
       <title>Manager</title>
       <edLevel>16</edLevel>
       <gender>F</gender>
       <birthDate>1976-05-15</birthDate>
       <salary>68400</salary>
       <bonus>1400</bonus>
       <commission>5500</commission>
   </employee>
</employees>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!--
   Employee Information from Department D21
   Filename:         deptd21.xml
-->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="alldepartments.xsl"?>
<employees>
   <employee empID="70">
       <firstName>William</firstName>
       <middleInt>P</middleInt>
       <lastName>Kimble</lastName>
       <department>D21</department>
       <phone>7831</phone>
       <email>Kimble.87@example.com/horizons</email>
       <dateHired>2015-09-30</dateHired>
       <title>Manager</title>
       <edLevel>16</edLevel>
       <gender>F</gender>
       <birthDate>1988-05-26</birthDate>
       <salary>83200</salary>
       <bonus>1600</bonus>
       <commission>6700</commission>
   </employee>
   <employee empID="230">
       <firstName>Kevin</firstName>
       <middleInt>J</middleInt>
       <lastName>Smith</lastName>
       <department>D21</department>
       <phone>2094</phone>
       <email>Smith.77@example.com/horizons</email>
       <dateHired>2001-11-21</dateHired>
       <title>Clerk</title>
       <edLevel>14</edLevel>
       <gender>M</gender>
       <birthDate>1970-05-30</birthDate>
       <salary>51000</salary>
       <bonus>900</bonus>
       <commission>4100</commission>
   </employee>
   <employee empID="240">
       <firstName>Patrick</firstName>
       <middleInt>M</middleInt>
       <lastName>Trexler</lastName>
       <department>D21</department>
       <phone>3780</phone>
       <email>Trexler.63@example.com/horizons</email>
       <dateHired>2014-12-05</dateHired>
       <title>Clerk</title>
       <edLevel>17</edLevel>
       <gender>M</gender>
       <birthDate>1989-03-31</birthDate>
       <salary>66100</salary>
       <bonus>1400</bonus>
       <commission>5300</commission>
   </employee>
</employees>
```

Comment: Let's hope those are not real names and data! This is a Public Website.

Comment: Also, showing desired XML output may be more illustrative than telling it in a long list.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the external `exsl:node-set()` to save a tree of your department codes which you then run through with `xsl:for-each`. Do note,  below only runs through the departments you have posted. Extend the *$deptList* for other available deptXXX.xml that MUST exist in current directory of stylesheet. Notice too you can reduce code by avoiding the `<xsl:element>` or `<xsl:attribute>` calls:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"                                                              
                              xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
                              exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
   <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="getEmployees"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="getEmployees">
      <xsl:variable name="deptList">
        <depts>
            <dept>a00</dept>
            <dept>d21</dept>
            <dept>e11</dept>            
        </depts>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:variable name="depts" select="ext:node-set($deptList)/depts/*"/>

       <departments>            
            <xsl:for-each select="$depts">
                <xsl:variable name="currentDept"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:variable>
                <department dept="{$currentDept}">
                    <xsl:if test="doc(concat('DeptEmployees',$currentDept, '.xml'))">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="doc(concat('dept',$currentDept, '.xml'))/employees" />
                    </xsl:if>
                </department>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </departments>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<departments>
   <department dept="a00">
      <employees>
         <employee empID="10">
            <firstName>Marylin</firstName>
            <middleInt>A</middleInt>
            <lastName>Johnson</lastName>
            <department>A00</department>
            <phone>3978</phone>
            <email>Johnson.60@example.com/horizons</email>
            <dateHired>2000-01-01</dateHired>
            <title>President</title>
            <edLevel>18</edLevel>
            <gender>F</gender>
            <birthDate>1968-08-24</birthDate>
            <salary>121300</salary>
            <bonus>2300</bonus>
            <commission>9700</commission>
         </employee>
         <employee empID="40">
            <firstName>Heather</firstName>
            <middleInt>D</middleInt>
            <lastName>Gordon</lastName>
            <department>A00</department>
            <phone>3915</phone>
            <email>Gordon.59@example.com/horizons</email>
            <dateHired>2009-03-01</dateHired>
            <title>Manager</title>
            <edLevel>18</edLevel>
            <gender>F</gender>
            <birthDate>1986-06-03</birthDate>
            <salary>85400</salary>
            <bonus>1700</bonus>
            <commission>6500</commission>
         </employee>
      </employees>
   </department>
   <department dept="d21">
      <employees>
         <employee empID="70">
            <firstName>William</firstName>
            <middleInt>P</middleInt>
            <lastName>Kimble</lastName>
            <department>D21</department>
            <phone>7831</phone>
            <email>Kimble.87@example.com/horizons</email>
            <dateHired>2015-09-30</dateHired>
            <title>Manager</title>
            <edLevel>16</edLevel>
            <gender>F</gender>
            <birthDate>1988-05-26</birthDate>
            <salary>83200</salary>
            <bonus>1600</bonus>
            <commission>6700</commission>
         </employee>
         <employee empID="230">
            <firstName>Kevin</firstName>
            <middleInt>J</middleInt>
            <lastName>Smith</lastName>
            <department>D21</department>
            <phone>2094</phone>
            <email>Smith.77@example.com/horizons</email>
            <dateHired>2001-11-21</dateHired>
            <title>Clerk</title>
            <edLevel>14</edLevel>
            <gender>M</gender>
            <birthDate>1970-05-30</birthDate>
            <salary>51000</salary>
            <bonus>900</bonus>
            <commission>4100</commission>
         </employee>
         <employee empID="240">
            <firstName>Patrick</firstName>
            <middleInt>M</middleInt>
            <lastName>Trexler</lastName>
            <department>D21</department>
            <phone>3780</phone>
            <email>Trexler.63@example.com/horizons</email>
            <dateHired>2014-12-05</dateHired>
            <title>Clerk</title>
            <edLevel>17</edLevel>
            <gender>M</gender>
            <birthDate>1989-03-31</birthDate>
            <salary>66100</salary>
            <bonus>1400</bonus>
            <commission>5300</commission>
         </employee>
      </employees>
   </department>
   <department dept="e11">
      <employees>
         <employee empID="50">
            <firstName>Alicia</firstName>
            <middleInt>J</middleInt>
            <lastName>Silva</lastName>
            <department>E11</department>
            <phone>6789</phone>
            <email>Silva.50@example.com/horizons</email>
            <dateHired>2013-08-17</dateHired>
            <title>Manager</title>
            <edLevel>16</edLevel>
            <gender>M</gender>
            <birthDate>1960-09-15</birthDate>
            <salary>92400</salary>
            <bonus>1800</bonus>
            <commission>7400</commission>
         </employee>
         <employee empID="90">
            <firstName>Ila</firstName>
            <middleInt>R</middleInt>
            <lastName>Leclerc</lastName>
            <department>E11</department>
            <phone>5498</phone>
            <email>Leclerc.51@example.com/horizons</email>
            <dateHired>2005-08-15</dateHired>
            <title>Manager</title>
            <edLevel>16</edLevel>
            <gender>F</gender>
            <birthDate>1976-05-15</birthDate>
            <salary>68400</salary>
            <bonus>1400</bonus>
            <commission>5500</commission>
         </employee>
      </employees>
   </department>
</departments>
```